# Unity3D - Array to Enum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

Using Unity3Ds built in EditorGUI System I would like to make the work of my gamedesigner easier by creating a custom editor for dialogue systems. I would like to be able to insert Item names into the Editor's `EnumPopup`. The problem is that my List/Array of Items is generated at runtime so I cant use it as an `enum`.

Every of my Items also has an assigned ItemID which makes the `enum` logic a bit easier.

How could I convert `Dictionary<int, Item>` to an `enum` which can be then used in ...

`EnumPopup(Enum selected, params GUILayoutOption[] options);`

Comment: An array/list/dictionary are completely different types of objects to enums - there is no conversion between the two. Your current design is incompatible with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `EditorGUILayout.Popup`? You can list your dictionary's values as a string and pass them to the popup as options.

Comment: Well it does not answer the initial question, but it is a solution for what the asker is trying to achieve. It was helpful to me

Comment: Well it surely is a solution to go around the `enum` part. Thank you!